# Firebase FCM Token Exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I do not know when to start debugging I am getting a Fatal Exception while developing an app.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: TokenRefresher
              Process: com.bitwise.rotaractclubapp, PID: 22226
              java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field PREFER_HIGHEST_OR_REMOTE_VERSION_NO_FORCE_STAGING of type Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule$VersionPolicy; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule' appears in /data/app/com.bitwise.rotaractclubapp-2/base.apk)
                  at com.google.android.gms.flags.c.a(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.flags.b.a(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.aa.a(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.x.run(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

This occurs when re-installing the app, I am saving a device token in database when the user's logged in or open the app like this.

```
 FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
        mDatabase.collection("Collection")
            .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .update("token", instanceIdResult.getToken());
    }
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: please add `dependencies` from the `build.gradle`. "no such field" hints for a missing one. Q: why would you want to store the auth-token into Firestore, which cannot be accessed when the token has expired?

Comment: Am I storing auth token? I thought it was a device token.

Comment: I am storing it for sending a notification on a specific device with cloud function

Comment: @MartinZeitler `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()` results in the device token, which identifies this specific app on this specific device. It's quite common to store these tokens in a registry, so that you can target notifications to specific devices.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for  the confirmation

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this at least explains the why (have confused the token's type) - nevertheless it is unclear why field `PREFER_HIGHEST_OR_REMOTE_VERSION_NO_FORCE_STAGING` is unknown to the `TokenRefresher`. I'd suspect some version conflict there; eg. an outdated Play Services library.

Comment: I ran into the error just a few minutes ago. Like @MartinZeitler said the problem is related to the Google Play Services' version. Upgraded from `com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0` to `com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0` and the error doesn't show up anymore.

Comment: I already update the dependency at still getting this error sometimes

Comment: @Mihae this does not sound logical, because when depending on a library - it should always be the exactly the same version of the library added into the package. manually deleting the `build` directories and gradle caches might help to get rid of all remaining outdated versions. and unless you would add your `build.gradle`, I'd almost have to vote to close this for "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: It seems like updating the version really fix the problem I am not getting any error until now.

Comment: The problem still exist for me, even with 4.1.0 version

Comment: The problem still exist for me, my google-service version is at 4.1.0