# FATAL EXCEPTION: Token Refresher using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, firebase-authentication

When I try to run my app via AndroidStudio I keep getting the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: TokenRefresher
Process: com.ruzzimedia.projecttaskr, PID: 31951
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field PREFER_HIGHEST_OR_REMOTE_VERSION_NO_FORCE_STAGING of type Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule$VersionPolicy; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule' appears in /data/app/com.ruzzimedia.projecttaskr-XxKs9V7Uuo8sUAVGakw3-Q==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
```

I've tried updating my dependencies and it results in the same error. I'm currently on the latest gradle dependency versions and I can't find the cause of the error. I'm also not sure what is calling the DynamiteModule in my app.

My Gradle Dependencies are listed below:

```
dependencies {
    def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha08"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha08"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha08"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.4'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck(true)
```

Comment: kindly provide ur code so we can know what you are missing

Comment: your error description alos seems to be short

Comment: @Jeeva what code do I need to show? The error past what I have posted traces back to an "unknown" source that I have to decompile to see. Let me know what to post here and I will.

Comment: please post your build.gradle dependencies

Comment: com.google.gms:google-services: what is this version??

Comment: @Jeeva I updated it now, I don't see any version for google-services

Comment: @Jeeva I just updated my google services to 4.2.0

Comment: above error appers if google play services is not up to date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52705403/6059583

Comment: @Jeeva That did the trick, thank you. I thought I had checked earlier but guess I hadn't haha. Thank you though.

Comment: post that as answer it may help others